# Installing Latex in python to change font of plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, tex

I am using the IDE Spyder and need to change the font on my plots to the same as Latex uses. I've seen the following instruction:

Matplotlib’s LaTeX support requires a working LaTeX installation, dvipng (which may be included with your LaTeX installation), and Ghostscript (GPL Ghostscript 8.60 or later is recommended). The executables for these external dependencies must all be located on your PATH.

But how do you do this?
Right now I am getting the error

```
Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found
```

Using:

```
mpl.rc('font', **{'family': 'serif', 'serif': ['Computer Modern']})
mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would double check that latex is on your path. Seeing that it can't be found is what makes me suspect that might be the case. I would also check that the other dependencies are there too.

Comment: How do you do this?

Comment: It depends on what operating system you are using. Actually check this link out: https://miktex.org/howto/modify-path